# Where do I access the book once I register on Kindle?

Tags: amazon, kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

If I buy a book on Kindle how do I access the book, is this done by going into my Amazon account and accessing the book directly?

Comment: You need a Kindle device or a Kindle app.

Comment: @AʟE. Actually, there is a Kindle web application. (The link is in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://read.amazon.com/ and sign in with the account used to buy the book.

Comment: there are many free books to test this out before going out of pocket.